# Finding businesses "At this location" via address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

We're using the Google Places API to return the results of a text search in which we pass an address to Google and it returns the Name of the business at this address. If it finds nothing, or there is only one business at that address (at least in the Places database), then this is straightforward. However, some addresses have multiple businesses and when searching these addresses on Google Maps, it provides "At this location" results like this:

At this location example
[image: image description]

Is there a way we return these "At this location results" via the API, or step into them to return the Place data?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be doing the trick for "BNZ" and "RSM" in your screenshot:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=businesses+near+86+Highbrook+Dr,+East+Tamaki,+Auckland+2013&radius=100&key=[Your Key]
```

Try playing around with `radius=[in meters]` in general and here's the documentation for Google API's Text Search endpoint:

```
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests
```

To find the other businesses in your screenshot, I retrieved the geocoded address (lat/long) from the result of the first query (with only the address), and then used that in the Nearby Search endpoint for the value of the location parameter:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-36.9397743,174.8685493&radius=100&key=[Your Key]

Here's the documentation for Nearby Search (unfortunately, it doesn't seem to take addresses for location, nor accept a query parameter):
https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

Note: I also specified `type=car_dealer&radius=1000` in the `textsearch` query with only the address (removed "businesses near"), and "Ford" didn't come up. So there may be different database indexing between Nearby Search and Text Search.

Comment: Thanks Andres, we have tried using radius from 0m upwards to 100m, although as you suggest but this isn't yielding the required result. Is there a way to extract just those list of companies (and their details) under 'At this location' using a single API? e.g. google places search 'at this location' API etc

Comment: Negative as far as I can tell from the place api docs. It's possible Google's "At this location" implementation might have its own internal API/DB. Also, that whatever db `textsearch` is retrieving from needs to be reindexed/debugged. It might be best to tag your question according to the recommendations seen here under "Community support on Stack Overflow" to see if someone with more internal knowledge can weigh-in: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/support

Answer (score 0):

There's this open source [nuget called GuigleCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GuigleCore/) that has a very similar feature to Google Map's "What's here". You can call either:

```
var place = await googlePlacesApi.GetExactPlaceByAddress(_client, "123 Street, Suburb A");
```

OR

```
var place = await googlePlacesApi.GetExactPlaceByLocation(_client, -11.111, 11.111);
```

And most times (if not always) it will return the same place as the Google Map's "What's here" feature.
It just needs to be instantiated with your Google Api Key. It can also be registered/injected using its interfaces.

```
var googlePlacesApi = new GooglePlacesApi("GoogleApiKey");
```

You can install it with the nuget command **Install-Package GuigleCore**